# SLF4J implementation over Log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

We have a application using `log4j version 1.2.17` for logging. Now we are recommended to use SLF4J since log4j 1.2.17 seems very old. I found one of the option is to use `SLF4J over Log4j` but I am not quite sure about the logging performance using SLF4J over Log4j. So, keeping mind that we have to implement in both Tomcat and Jboss 7.2, using `SLF4J alone` is better or SLF4J over Log4j is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name of SLF4J suggest, it is only a "Facade".

Therefore, simply having SLF4J itself is not going to work.  You need an backend that actually handle the logging request from SLF4J.

As you can imagine, using SLF4J + Log4J, performance-wise it is not going to be better than Log4J itself.  However, it give you flexibility to switch to other logging backend.

There is a SLF4J-native logging backend which named Logback.  It is believed that Logback out-performs Log4J.  That means, SLF4J+Logback > Log4J > SLF4J+Log4J .